# date validation in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, date

im creating a hotel booking system using asp.net. I'm using drop down list to allow user to choose the days and month. Lets say today's date is 15/2. but my system allow user to choose the date before that. How do i prevent user from choosing dates before the current date?

Comment: compare it with `Datetime.Today`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery datepicker and use the on select event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Date').datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //Get today's date at midnight
            var today = new Date();
            today = Date.parse(today.getMonth()+1+'/'+today.getDate()+'/'+today.getFullYear());
            //Get the selected date (also at midnight)
            var selDate = Date.parse(dateText);

            if(selDate < today) {
                //If the selected date was before today, continue to show the datepicker
                $('#Date').val('');
                $(inst).datepicker('show');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/ZW7cs/34/) demo

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

try JQuery DatePicker :-(You'll Find Solution Here)
http://allittechnologies.blogspot.in/2015/05/aspnet-choose-date-by-using-jquery-in-software-it-technologies.html

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to provide the actual information here and not just a link. [Link-only answers are not considered good answers and will probably be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).